# What is the difference between .cfg and .conf in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, centos

it seems so many configuration files in linux,
some files having extension .cfg and some files having .conf

Little bit confusion, what is the difference .cfg and .conf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no particular meaning. Both are short for "configuration". There's no real standard for what configuration files should be called.

Apparently the authors of some programs preferred `.conf`, and others preferred `.cfg`.

If you need to create a configuration file for a particular program, you just have to use the name that program expects.